# Ubuntu live USB works on surface 6 but doesn't work on Alienware 17

Tags: live-usb

I have a ubuntu 20.04 live USB working on a surface 6 perfectly. However, when I boot the system on a Alienware laptop, the system becomes slow and the applications will open neither. The network manager also stops working on Alienware laptop. Is there anything I can do? To provide more information: I created my live USB using Rufus and the ubuntu file downloaded from the ubuntu website.

Comment: When you say boot the system on the laptop are you saying trying to boot live USB? Question is unclear.

Comment: Please specify more details about the two computers: Brand names and models of the computers themselves, of the graphics chips/cards and of the wifi chips/cards. It is important also to specify the models, because they can differ a lot, and may need different hardware drivers (or in worst case lack a working hardware driver).

Comment: Yes, When I say boot system I mean boot from USB. Like when the computer is starting, pressing F12 to select the boot option.

Comment: The surface I am using is a Microsoft Surface 6 with Intel(R) Core i5. The Alienware 17 has an Intel(R) Core i7 with Nivida GTX 1060.  In the Surface, the Network Adapters are called WAN Miniport. On the Alienware I believe the wifi chip is called Killer E2500 Gigabit Ethernet Controller.

Comment: Information Update: the Live USB works normally on Alienware now, and all I have done is unplugging the charger from Alienware. It seems like that Alienware won't shut down completely when you are charging it. And I guess that's the reason my USB didn't work before?